# Can I deploy a spring-boot 2.0 WAR on a Tomcat 8.0.x?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

spring-boot 2.0 has been available for a week now. The blog posts mention that there's now a Tomcat 8.5 baseline for embedded tomcat.

Does that also mean I need to have a Tomcat 8.5 if I use WAR deployment of my spring-boot 2.0 application, or would a Tomcat 8.0.x still work?

Comment: Do you want us to try deploying to Tomcat 8.0.x for you to see if it works?

Comment: Not really, because maybe it works for most of the features but breaks on something my application uses, but yours doesn't. I'd prefer somebody answering yes or no because he or she knows what exactly the 8.5 baseline is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official Spring Boot 2.0.0 documentation points to Tomcat 8.5 as the baseline version for embedded servers.

[Spring Framework 5.0 itself requires Servlet 3.1+ containers and Tomcat 8.5+](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#baseline-update) for both embedded and war deployments.

Although deploying Spring MVC applications to a Tomcat 8.0.x server might still work, it won't be officially supported by Spring Framework nor Spring Boot.

Comment: Thank you, Brian.

Comment: Hi but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat tomcat 8.0.x supports Servlet 3.1...

Comment: Apache Tomcat 8.0.x builds on Tomcat 7.0.x and implements the Servlet 3.1, JSP 2.3, EL 3.0 and WebSocket 1.1 specifications. In addition to that, it includes the following significant improvements:

Comment: True. But Spring Framework officially supports Tomcat 8.5+. You’re free to deploy on 8.0, it’s your call